# When does a matrix have $LDL^T$ decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have limited experience with matrix analysis, yet I've come across several related questions in practical applications.

In all questions, permutations are allowed, i.e., it's ok to have $A=PLDL^TP^{-1}$.

1. Suppose that $A$ is a $n\times n$ **real symmetric** matrix. What is the necessity and sufficiency for $A$ to have $LDL^T$ decomposition (say $L$ is a lower triangular matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix)?
2. What if $A$ is complex symmetric (not Hermitian)?
3. What if $A$ is Hermitian?
4. Can arbitrary **invertible** complex symmetric matrix $A$ have $LDL^T$ decomposition?

As for $LU$ decomposition with permutations, it seems that $A$ has $LU$ decomposition $\Leftrightarrow$ $A$ is invertible.

Anything could be helpful! Thank you in advance.

Related questions:
[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504209/when-does-a-real-symmetric-matrix-have-ldlt-decomposition-and-when-is-the) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576552/could-every-symmetric-matrix-m-ldu-be-re-written-as-ldl) [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182984/is-there-any-sufficient-or-necessary-conditions-for-a-matrix-to-have-lu-factoriz)